# Help find the laplace transformation

Tags: laplace-transform

Given that

$L\{J_0(t)\}=1/(s^2+1)$

where $J_0(t)=\sum\limits^{∞}_{n=0}(−1)n(n!)2(t2)2n$,

find the Laplace transform of $tJ_0(t)$.

$L\{tJ_0(t)\}=$_***_*__*_*__*_*___**---___?

Comment: Do you mean the Bessel function $J_0(t)$?

Comment: Is this the series you are given $$ 
    J_0(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! m!} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m}\,?  $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the tables:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt\: J_0(t) e^{-s t} = (1+s^2)^{-1/2}$$

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt\:t J_0(t) e^{-s t} = -\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^{\infty} dt\: J_0(t) e^{-s t} = s (1+s^2)^{-3/2}  $$

Comment: Hello.Ron i apologize. Im new to this and didnt know there was a place to rate your answers. If you can help guide me towards what i need to do in order to satisfy this websites requirements. Regards

Comment: @MichaelRametta: no need to apologize for anything.  If you post a question and you see an answer you like, upvote it if you can (I think you need a minimum rep score, I forget what).  If you find one of the solutions meets your expectations of usefulness, clarity, etc., then accept it.  By accepting it, you are telling the rest of the community that the question has been answered, so it is good practice to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the property

$$ L(t^n f(x)) =  (-1)^{n} F^{(n)}(s),  $$

where $F(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(x)$.